# rails6 + Bootstrap4 + RSpec トグル表示のリンクやモーダルのテストについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

**嵌っていること**

---

1. Navbar上のトグルスイッチを押してドロップメニューを表示
2. メニューの中のログインのリンクを押すとログイン用フォームをモーダルで表示
3. フォーム全部空欄で’送信’ボタンを押し、モーダル上でエラーメッセージが出ることを確認する

アプリ上では動くのですが、一連の動作をどうやってRSpecで表記すればよいのか分からず詰まっています。
ご教授いただければ有難いです。

**環境**

---

主なGemfileは以下です

```
ruby '2.7.4'

gem 'bootstrap',                  '~> 4.6.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails',                      '6.0.3'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'sass-rails',                 '5.1.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails',             '~> 3.2.2'
gem 'turbolinks',                 '5.2.0'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker',                  '~> 3.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails',       '~> 5.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'sqlite3',           '1.4.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.28.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.4'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.4'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.1.2'
end
```

spec/rails_helpの主な内容が以下です

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
#capybara内のmethodを読み込む
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!


  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end

  config.include ApplicationHelper
  #signup_pathがundefinedと言われたので入れてみた
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  #強制的にCapybara::DSLを読み込む
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end

#shoulda matcherを入れる
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
# トグルSWやモーダルなどで非表示になっているものをtestするため
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

# Capybaraのdriverを指定してみる(デフォルトは:rack_test)
Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test
# jsオプション有効時のドライバを設定(デフォルトは:selenium)
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

#任意の場所でScreenshotを撮るために用意する
def take_screenshot
  page.save_screenshot "tmp/capybara/screenshot-#{DateTime.now}.png"
end
```

layouts/_navbar.html.erbの抜粋は以下です

```
# <div class="modal fade role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">はappeication.html.erbに記載

   <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-secondary">
       <div class="container">
            <a id="logo" class="navbar-brand" href='/'>
                <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-heart"></i>
                ブランド
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="humberger"    
                    data-toggle="collapse"  
                    data-target="#navcol-1"
                    aria-controls="#navcol-1" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="#navcol-1">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-light" href='/'>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <%= link_to "ログイン", login_path, remote: true, 
                            class: "text-light", id: "modal-open" %>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="text-light" href='/signup'>新規登録</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

layouts/sessions/_login_form-modal.html.erbの内容が以下です

```
<!-- ログインフォーム用モーダル   -->
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">ログイン</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <hr style="margin-bottom: 3px">
    <div class="modal-body">

        <%= form_with(url: login_path, scope: :session, 
                                       class: 'js-form') do |f| %>
          <!-- ここにエラーメッセージが出る-->
          <div class="js-message-error"></div>

          <%= f.label :email, "メールアドレス" %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

          <%= f.label :password, "パスワード" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

          <hr />
          
          <%= f.submit "送信", class: "mt2 btn btn-info form-btn float-right" %>
      
        <% end %>   
         
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

テストを試みているファイル（spec/systems/sessions_spec.rb）は以下です

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Sessions', type: :system do
  before do
    visit root_path
  end

  it 'モーダルが表示されるか', js: true do 
      find(".navbar-toggler").click
      sleep 0.5
      take_screenshot
      page.evaluate_script('$(".fade").removeClass("fade")')
      click_link 'ログイン'
      sleep 0.5
      is_expected.to have_selector(text: "メールアドレス")
  end
    
  #一連の流れを以下のように書きましたが、うまくいかず、上記のexampleを書いて確認を試みました。
    # #モーダルを表示して無効な値を入力する
    # describe 'enter an invalid values', js: true do
    #   before do
    #   find(".navbar-toggler").click
    #   page.evaluate_script('$(".fade").removeClass("fade")')
    #   click_link 'ログイン' 
    #   fill_in 'メールアドバイス', with: ''
    #   fill_in 'パスワード', with: ''
    #   click_button '送信'
    # end
    # #エラーメッセージが出る
    # it 'gets an error message' do
    #   is_expected.to have_selector(text: "入力内容に誤りがあります")
    # end
    # #一度モーダルを閉じる
    # context 'close modal' do
    #   before do
    #     click_on 'x'
        
    #     click_on 'ログイン'
    #   end
    #   #エラーメッセージが消える
    #   it 'is message disappear' do
    #     is_expected.to_not have_selector(text: "入力内容に誤りがあります" )
    #   end
  #   end
  # end
end
```

エラーの内容です

```
Failures:

  1) Sessions モーダルが表示されるか
     Failure/Error: click_link 'ログイン'
     
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError:
       element not interactable
         (Session info: headless chrome=93.0.4577.82)
     
     [Screenshot]: toggleが開いておらずプルダウンが出てないスクリーンショット

     
     # 0   chromedriver                        0x0000000100c976d9 chromedriver + 2758361
     # 1   chromedriver                        0x000000010134a893 chromedriver + 9783443
     # 2   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a2298f chromedriver + 182671
     # 3   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a57f39 chromedriver + 401209
     # 4   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a4c358 chromedriver + 353112
     # 5   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a74022 chromedriver + 516130
     # 6   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a4c0e5 chromedriver + 352485
     # 7   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a7429e chromedriver + 516766
     # 8   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a86514 chromedriver + 591124
     # 9   chromedriver                        0x0000000100a74243 chromedriver + 516675
     # 10  chromedriver                        0x0000000100a4aa0e chromedriver + 346638
     # 11  chromedriver                        0x0000000100a4bc75 chromedriver + 351349
     # 12  chromedriver                        0x0000000100c5e1df chromedriver + 2523615
     # 13  chromedriver                        0x0000000100c709f2 chromedriver + 2599410
     # 14  chromedriver                        0x0000000100c4302b chromedriver + 2412587
     # 15  chromedriver                        0x0000000100c71e1a chromedriver + 2604570
     # 16  chromedriver                        0x0000000100c5396c chromedriver + 2480492
     # 17  chromedriver                        0x0000000100c8bd38 chromedriver + 2710840
     # 18  chromedriver                        0x0000000100c8bec1 chromedriver + 2711233
     # 19  chromedriver                        0x0000000100c9c6f8 chromedriver + 2778872
     # 20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff204a78fc _pthread_start + 224
     # 21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff204a3443 thread_start + 15
     # ./spec/systems/sessions_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'

Finished in 6.9 seconds (files took 1.23 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/systems/sessions_spec.rb:8 # Sessions モーダルが表示されるか
```

**やってみたこと**

---

qiitaの記事などを参考に
`js: true` を入れる、`sleep`で少し待つ、`page.evaluate_script('$(".fade").removeClass("fade")')`を入れてみる
を試みましたが、どれも効果がありませんでした。
スクショではそもそもプルダウンが開いていないので、何か根本的に誤りがあるのかもと感じています

何かお気づきの点があればご指摘いただきたく。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

よくわかりませんが、自己解決できたようです。
理由は皆目わかりませんが、

```
  it 'モーダルが表示されるか', js: true do
      find(".navbar-toggler").click
      expect(page).to have_link 'ログイン', href: login_path, visible: false
      page.evaluate_script('$(".fade").removeClass("fade")')
      click_link 'ログイン'
      expect(page).to have_content('メールアドレス')
  end
```

これでモーダルの表示は確認できました。
`sleep`を消していますが、別にあってもなくても結果は変わらないので消しています。
何がきっかけで通ったのかは正直全くわかりません。困惑しております。
これを参考にして、やりたかったテストを以下のように記載しました。

```
    context '無効な値を入力したとき', js: true do
      before do
      find(".navbar-toggler").click
      page.evaluate_script('$(".fade").removeClass("fade")')
      click_on 'ログイン'
      fill_in 'メールアドレス', with: ''
      fill_in 'パスワード', with: ''
      click_button '送信'
      end
      
      it 'エラーメッセージが出ること' do
        expect(page).to have_content('入力内容に誤りがあります')
      end

    context 'モーダルを一度閉じて再度開いたとき', js: true do
      before do
        page.evaluate_script("$('#login-modal').modal('hide')")
        click_on 'ログイン'
      end
      it 'エラーメッセージが消えていること' do
        expect(page).to_not have_content('入力内容に誤りがあります')
      end
    end
  end
```

これでテストが通りましたので一先ずよしとしてます。